# How to add "Attachment" in Google Apps Calendar using Google API version 2?

Tags: c#, attachment, google-calendar-api

I am using Google API Version 2 fo .NET to create Google Calendar Entries. 
How can i add "Attachment" to Google Calendar?

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

For all the future generations reading this, the attachments are now supported, here is the guide on how to do it: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events#attachments

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to find the answer to this question myself, and after looking through the XML results for various queries using the [Calendar API feeds](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide.html), I'm pretty sure there isn't currently a way to retrieve or update file attachments. Since calendar event file attachments is a lab feature from Google, it's not entirely surprising that they aren't yet available through the public API.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you could use [extended properties](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#ExtendedProps) to store additional information about attachments in an event, but these values won't be read by the calendar web client, so you would only be able to use them for your own application.

A couple other things (admittedly hacks) you could try:

- The ICAL feed provided by Google
  Calendar provides an ATTACH:
  property. You could have your app use
  the import url to import an ics file
  containing your attachment.
- You could
  simulate the web client, which posts
  a gdoc-attachment parameter to update
  an events with an attachment.

You also might try posting to the calendar help forums. The only related post I could find was [here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-apis/thread?tid=0c55649b30bda1a7&hl=en).

Good luck!